# C++ wstring to enum

Tags: c++, enums, type-conversion

I have defined an enum like this:

```
enum eFeature
{
    eF_NONE=0,
    eF_PORT_A=1,
    eF_PORT_B=2,
    eF_PORT_C=3,
};
```

I would now like to convert a wstring (which is either "0", "1", "2" or "3") to eFeature.

I tried

```
eFeature iThis;
iThis = _wtoi(mystring.c_str());
```

But the compiler tells me "A value of type 'int' can not be assigned to an entity of the type eFeature."

Can somebody help?
Thank you.

Comment: Your enum ranges from 0 to 3, while the wstring values include "4". Is that an extra challenge, or just a typo?

Comment: Read about [type casting in C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions#Conversions).

Comment: @MrLister Sorry, a typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are attempting to assign an `int` to an `enum`, which is not allowed. Leaving the `wstring` distraction aside, what you are doing is the equivalent of

```
eFeature iThis;
iThis = 42;
```

You first need to cast the `int` to the `enum` type:

```
eFeature iThis;
iThis = static_cast<eFeature>(42);
```

Obviously, you would need to perform some kind of range checking first.

Comment: @user2421725: Trust me when I say, do this in a function.  Preferably `eFeature eFeature_from_string(const std::wstring&)`.